# ./startFabric command can't startUp peer0.org1.example.com container

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Env:

- Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
- Hyperledger Composer 0.19.1

When I use `./startFabric.sh` command to start a network.
The peer0.org1.example.com container cann't startUp. Show warnning below:

`2018-05-06 01:32:11.118 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 016 Retrying couchdb request in 125ms. Attempt:1  Error:Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp 172.18.0.4:5984: getsockopt: connection refused`

I have try adding `dns_search:.` option in composer file, but it not works.

Answer (score 1):

As I had the same issue and @T_murder's post is in chinese, I tried to understand it with google translate. And basically, adding `GODEBUG=netdns=go` to the environment variables of ca, orderer and peer in the docker-compose.yml file solved it for him and for me.